# How to treat unique constraint violations in a data migration script?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert, constraints, unique-constraint

Here I'm trying to migrate some data from a table column to a brand new table in which destination column have an unique constraint. Basically I'm trying to:

```
INSERT INTO FooTable VALUES (SELECT BarTable.Code FROM BarTable)
```

FooTable have only 2 columns: ID and Code (column with unique constraint).

But on BarTable.Code, maybe there are some duplicate values that I need to treat and fit them in the new constraint (maybe: Code = Code + 1 or else).

Any ideas on how to do that?

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) command and insert a different record when the codes match.

Here is an example based on your scenario:

```
MERGE FooTable AS T
USING BarTable AS S
ON (T.Code = S.Code) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT(Code) VALUES(S.Code)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT(Code) VALUES(S.Code+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Not Exists`

```
INSERT INTO FooTable VALUES (SELECT distinct br.Code FROM BarTable br where NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM FooTable bs where br.code=bs.code  ) )
```